# How to extract "foo" from "foo-bar-baz" in bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing, string, text

I'm trying to extract `foo` from the string `"foo-bar-baz"` in bash.

Any ideas how to do it using string substitution or something similar (without external tools).

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"
$ echo ${str%-*}
foo-bar
```

This also not work:

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"
$ echo ${str#*-}
bar-baz
```

Any ideas how to get just `bar`?

Comment: Cross-posted on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013860/how-to-extract-foo-from-foo-bar-baz-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"

$ echo "${str%%-*}"
foo

$ echo "${str##*-}"
baz

$ var="${str#*-}"
$ echo "$var"
bar-baz
$ echo "${var%-*}"
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This might extract foo from the string.

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"
str= ${str%-*} #this will get the part foo-bar
str= ${str%-*} #this will fetch foo from the string foo-bar
echo $str
```

Comment: True but terrible in more ways than one.

Answer (score 0):

@heemayl already gave the correct answer, but to add the reference and explanation:

From `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
          Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as  in  pathname  expansion.   If  the  pattern
          matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parame-
          ter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘‘%’’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘‘%%’’ case) deleted.
```

You were only using a single `%` sign, so the shortest match was removed instead of the longest match.

And as a side note, I recently read a very accurate observation that people who learn `bash` and don't learn `awk` often end up using `bash` for text-processing jobs where it is [entirely and completely the wrong tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943).  I learned 90% of `awk` (everything but the more advanced functions) in about 5 hours—one evening and one morning.

If all you're doing is stripping out this one string to use as a file name or a command argument or something, then of course that's fine and that's why the functionality exists in `bash` at all.  However, if you're doing more advanced and complicated string juggling, I *highly* recommend spending a day learning `awk`.  It will pay off several dozen times over.

(I mention this mostly because your tags make it seem likely that `awk` would be a bigger help to you than `bash` string juggling.)